# magento 2 - remove Customizable Options for all products?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, database, admin, custom-options

how I can delete / remove Customizable Options for all products?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Try below code**

```
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    include('app/bootstrap.php');
    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('global');

    $products = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->getCollection();
    $count = 0 ;
    echo 'Custom Option Remove Start.<br/>';
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $product = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory')->create()->load($product->getId());
        if ($product->getHasOptions()) {
            $temp = [];
            $product->setOptions($temp);
            $product->setHasOptions(0)->save();
            echo "Update ".$product->getName()." ID:".$product->getId()." <br/>";
            $count++;
        }
    }
    echo 'Custom Option Remove Done.';
```

Comment: Hi thank you, but I don't know why after execution I have a blank page, you have any idea?

Comment: You have no any custom option product that why. have you check this line is print or not echo 'Custom Option Remove Start.<br/>';

Comment: I have a lot of custom options there but the file after I loaded is blank

Comment: in fact I observe that every code that I put in the php file is blank ...

Comment: I enable reporting and I have this error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager' not found in /home/public_html/rm_co.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/public_html/rm_co.php on line 5

Comment: please check I add this and everything is fine now.